# Birt page headers and footers

Tags: java, birt

Is it possible to add headers and footers to a birt report programmaticly? I need to add page numbers, page count, page n of m, date, and file name and things like this. I know how to do this in the eclipse report designer, but I need to do this in java. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible using Java. Although this is a much more overall tutorial, please take a look at the link below. Also note that you can find more references online for how to create BIRT tutorials using Java.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Build_Dynamic_Table_(BIRT)